# Undefined offset: 0, if metadata value is 0

Tags: php, wordpress

Using [Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields](https://github.com/webdevstudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) to get and post specific values. I'm getting errors from every metabox function if it's metadata value is 0. In this example I have a shortcode metabox and it sits inside content-pictorial.php:

```
<?php

        $slider_shortcode = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_cmb_slider_shortcode_text", false);
        if ($slider_shortcode[0]=="") { ?> // error line

        <!-- If there are no custom fields, show nothing -->

        <?php } else { ?>

          <?php foreach($slider_shortcode as $slider_shortcode) {
                echo do_shortcode(''.$slider_shortcode.''); 
              } ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

and this template is pulled in by this:

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'textorial');
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

                    get_template_part( 'content', 'textorial' );

                endwhile; 
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So `var_dump($slider_shortcode)` and see it's contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$slider_shortcode[0]` will only exist if that post contains the custom field `_cmb_slider_shortcode_text`

instead of

```
if ($slider_shortcode[0]=="")
```

use

```
if(count($slider_shortcode) < 1)
```